# Is the Universe an isolated system?

Tags: thermodynamics, universe, stars, observable-universe

I am not a physicist but this question has bugged me for a while now. The second law of thermodynamics states that the total entropy of an isolated system can never decrease over time. However, if the Universe is considered to be an isolated system, which as far as I know many people suggest, wouldn’t the formation of stars cause a decrease of the entropy?